# Select rows with same value and then insert a null record

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have written an query but it inserts alternate null columns. I want the null column after different orderids. Suppose i have two orderids 100 and 101. i have only one record for orderid 100 and two records for orderid 101 so it should insert null column after orderid 100 and then after 101 orderid.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE 
(
    srno int identity (1,1) ,
    orderid int,
    orderdate datetime,
    orderstatus varchar(255),
    product_name varchar(255),
    shipping_cost decimal(18,2),
    Quantity int,
    TotalPrice money,
    SalesTax1 money,
    CVV2_Response varchar(255),
    ShipFirstName varchar(255),
    ShipLastName varchar(255),
    ShipAddress1 varchar(255),
    ShipCity varchar(255),
    ShipState varchar(255),
    ShipPostalCode varchar(255),
    EmailAddress varchar(255),
    CustomerID int

)

SELECT CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.orderid end as orderid,CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.orderdate end as orderdate, 
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.OrderStatus end as Orderstatus, 
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.productname end as Productname,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.Quantity end as Quantity,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.TotalPrice end AS PaymentAmount,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.SalesTax1 ELSE 0.0 END AS Tax ,
CASE WHEN row_no = 1 THEN ord.totalshippingcost ELSE 0.0 END AS Totalshippingcost,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.CVV2_Response end as CVV2_Response  ,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.ShipFirstName end as ShipFirstName ,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.ShipLastName end as ShipLastName ,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.ShipAddress1 end as ShipAddress1 ,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.ShipCity end as ShipCity ,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.ShipState end as ShipState ,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.ShipPostalCode  end as ShipPostalCode,
CASE D.N WHEN 1 THEN ord.EmailAddress end AS CustomerEmail

FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ord.orderid ORDER BY ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, ord.OrderStatus, odn.productname, odn.Quantity, odn.TotalPrice,ord.SalesTax1,ord.totalshippingcost,ord.CVV2_Response ,ord.ShipFirstName ,ord.ShipLastName ,
ord.ShipAddress1 ,ord.ShipCity ,ord.ShipState ,ord.ShipPostalCode ,cus.EmailAddress) AS row_no, ord.orderid, 
ord.orderdate, ord.OrderStatus, odn.productname, odn.Quantity, odn.TotalPrice,ord.SalesTax1,ord.totalshippingcost,ord.CVV2_Response ,ord.ShipFirstName ,ord.ShipLastName ,
ord.ShipAddress1 ,ord.ShipCity ,ord.ShipState ,ord.ShipPostalCode ,cus.EmailAddress
FROM Orders AS ord 
    INNER JOIN orderdetails AS odn ON odn.orderid = ord.orderid INNER Join Customers AS cus on  ord.CustomerID = cus.CustomerID WHERE ord.OrderStatus = 'Processing'
) ord
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS D(N)
ORDER BY ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, ord.productname, D.N
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as order by:

```
order by row_number() over(order by ord.orderid, ord.orderdate, ord.productname)
```